# calculating distance to 1 (positive and negative numbers)

Tags: normalization, algorithms, distance-functions

I have what I assume is a very simple question.

I have a range of numbers from 81 to -6, that corresponds to racios pop. growth/urban construction of cities. The ideal ratio would be = 1. I need, therefore, to calculate the distance to 1 (the ideal value) to see which city is closer to the ideal value. If I was dealing with only positive numbers I'd know how to do this, however my lack of mathmatical knowledge doesn't allow me to solve this problem.

I hope you can help me. 
Much appreciated,

Marta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to calculate the absolute value of the difference between the numbers.

Example:

abs(76-1) = 75

abs(-5-1) = 6

The absolute value of a number, no matter if it is negative or possitive, is the distance to the origin. In your case, the "origin" is the 1, so you need to include that when calculating the distance.

For more information on absolute value see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

Answer (score 2):

Negative ratios make sense here because city populations can go down. (Question: Are there cases in which both population growth and urban construction are negative?)

Although @sdiabr is right as a matter of arithmetic that $|$ ratio $-\ 1|$ is a valid scale, I would be surprised if either that or ratio $-\ 1$ or ratio was always the best scale on which to work, e.g. for graphing results or regression-type modelling.

The cube root of ratio $-\ 1$ or asinh(ratio $-\ 1$) or sign(ratio $-\ 1$) log(|ratio $-\ 1$|) might be useful scales. Graphs would be better labelled with the ratios as recorded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Nick Cox. Urban construction can't go down because my data focuses on only the new buildings (i.e. it doesnt count demolished buildings). I think I might have a problem there, as I was now interpreting my results. But I guess it is better to formulate it in a different question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Where did -6 come from?

Comment: by dividing the proportion of new buildings and population growth of one city - thus, there are more new  buildings than "new people". Perhaps, you can read the following post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342235/how-to-interpret-ratios-between-different-units
I suppose I make it more clear there

Comment: The -6 comes from the following values:
in city x,
population growth (2001-2011)  -97 (negative population growth)
%of new buildings (2001 - 2011) +17

Comment: I'd just plot the two variables and then decide what summary makes sense, perhaps none at all.